# add separate search box for datatable possible?

Tags: php, datatable

I have searched it n dint found proper answer.

I want to add separate search box in datatable instead single one that is default.

Is it possible to add ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by that "separate search box in datatable" ?

Comment: search box for each column !!!

Comment: Have you tried it by yourself ? Did you write any code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this ?

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

It is given with example !! Please try this

Comment: it is working for me statically,will try for dynamic records thank you